# How delete initialized didn't saved nested object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have some question.

I initialize Object (eg. List) with three nested objects (eg. Item) without saving.

```
@list = List.new
@list.items.build(position: 1)
@list.items.build(position: 2)
@list.items.build(position: 3)
```

And I want to delete/destroy position with position = 3. How do that?

I have tried delete item like this:

```
@list.items.select {|item| item.position == 3 }.delete
```

But still @list.items.size is 3. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `@list.items.where(position: 3).destroy_all`

Comment: @RajarshiDas He wants to delete one model, not all of them.

Comment: oooh one record ? `@list.items.find_by(position: 3).destroy`

Comment: @RajarshiDas he already tried something similar

Comment: he needs to use `destroy` instead of `delete` because of this https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5142d5411481c893f817c1431b0869be3745060f/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L171

Comment: @RajarshiDas The models aren't persisted so `destroy_row` won't execute.

Comment: yes change my post Thank you @Jesper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to presume that these objects are ActiveRecord models.

Have you persisted the models? `delete` is something you would run a persisted model. It doesn't make much sense on unpersisted stuff. Also, to remove something from a collection you would usually run the delete method on the collection itself:

```
@list.items.delete(@list.items.select {|i| i.position == 3 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `delete_at`? And pass in the index of the item you want to remove. Note that this method returns the item removed.

```
@list.items.delete_at(2)
```